# Error in build path maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new in java and maven i faced this problem when importing this project

Can someone help on this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What build path errors do you have?

Comment: it's empty , and location unknown

Comment: Usually in eclipse a clean and update of the Maven project helps: Right-click on the project, select 'Maven' and select 'Update Project'.

Comment: thanks for helping but why some folders have a question mark i posted another screen shot for the problem

Comment: The question mark means some files in that folder are not tracked by version control, probably Git.

Comment: how can i solve it ?

Comment: There is no problem to resolve. This is a normal behavior. These files are new, and you may want to commit them to your working branch. More specifically, as I can see the new files are temporary backup files as they have a `~` at the end of the name. You can delete them, and you may want to configure eclipse in Window-Preferences-Team-SVN not to keep temporary files.

Comment: Many thanks for helping ,so it's not problem to let them in the project !

Answer (score 0):

Answer as sanastasiadis  said

Usually in eclipse a clean and update of the Maven project helps: Right-click on the project, select 'Maven' and select 'Update Project'. –